# Invoking SAS script using python - subprocess

Tags: python, sas, subprocess, popen

I am trying to invoke a sas script using python and subprocess. This is my code:

```py
    proc = Popen(self.cmd, shell=True, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    proc.wait()
    standard_output, standard_error = proc.communicate()
    if proc.returncode == 0:
        log.info("Successfully executed execute_shell_command")
    elif proc.returncode == 1:
        self.status_message = "return code 1 from" + " ".join(self.cmd) + "error msg: " + str(standard_error)
        self.flag = 1
        raise ValueError(self.status_message)
    elif proc.returncode > 1:
        self.status_message = "Error occurred while executing command on shell :" + " ".join(self.cmd) + ' ' + standard_error
        self.flag = 1
        raise ValueError(self.status_message)

    self.cmd  = [sas_path,'-config',sas_config_path,'-sysin',sas_code_path]
```

I am not including the autoexec_path for SAS,because I did not find any autoexec file.
if I have the autoexec file then,

```py
self.cmd = [sas_path,'-config',sas_config_path,'-autoexec',autoexec_path,'-sysin',sas_code_path]
```

The problem is the SAS code executes successfully, but `proc.returncode` is not equal to 0. Therefore, my python code doesn't know that the code ran successfully.
Is there anything that I am doing wrong?

Comment: can you set -log option and check whats wrong?

Comment: My sas code issued warnings,which is why the return code was 1.

Answer (score 1):

You might have warnings in the log.

From the docs, ["SAS® 9.4 Companion for Windows, Fifth Edition"](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/hostwin/69955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0d8f2zgsbjtqwn1f384lia2nlbm.htm)

> **Return Codes and Completion Status**
>
> The return code for the completion of a SAS job is returned in the Windows batch variable, ERRORLEVEL.
>
> …
>
> **Values for the ERRORLEVEL Variable**
>
> [image]

Comment: Thanks Richard. My SAS code log had warnings, which is why I was getting return code 1. This was very helpful.

Comment: Good to hear that and welcome to SO.  Be sure to mark answers to your questions and answers to other questions you find helpful.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers